# How can I deal a team member who is irresponsible and shows no commitment?

Tags: project-management, team

I am handling a team of a few guys working on a software module in a large project. As per our estimates our module is getting delayed by a week. Since we can not have this delay, our client and our manager arrive at a decision that we need to work on few weekends (3-4) to try to finish the work.

All members of the team are aware of this and understand this and since its just a matter of 3-4 extra days, so we decide to work on weekends to meet the deadline.

But one of the team members is not following this. From last three weekends he has some or the other reason to not come on weekend.

He is not even willing to put up extra hours during weekdays. Personally I don't care about the number of hours he works as long as he/(any one) can finish their work to meet the deadline.

Please let me know how to handle this situation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about professionalism and people management, not programming. Please ask such questions on http://workplace.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Does his contract say that he is expected to work overtime when required?

Comment: What country are you in? The laws are different, depending on the country. This will affect answers for sure.

Comment: @razethestray We used to have every 2nd saturday working. Later it was made non working on a condition that if it requires we will need to work on saturdays. Anyways we will be getting comp offs for working on weekends.

Comment: Sounds like more an estimate issue than a commitment issue. Not everyone lives for work. Some of us work to live.

Comment: @user99163 The employee shouldn't suffer for poor management decisions. You will chase away talented people really quickly if that is the normal.

Comment: @user99163 You guys taking up the extra work is up to you but you honestly can't expect someone to throw their life/work out of balance for a poor management decision without their consent or compensation for the extra effort.

Comment: @user99163: you can flag the post to request it be moved. Use the *Other* option.

Comment: *"he has some or the other reason to not come on weekend"* - I believe those reasons are called 'life'.

Comment: Was he consulted by the people who "decided" that he would have to do extra work? Would receive extra compensation for the extra work that's suddenly being "required" of him? No and no? Well, then it's not him that's being irresponsible and not showing commitment. It's your manager. You should be grateful that this team member is still with you at all.

Comment: And, wait... you told the client that he would work extra hours during the weekday, you did this without talking to him, and then you were surprised when you found out later that he wasn't willing to do it?

Comment: The interesting thing about these "large projects" is how they always need a "few weekends", and strangely, those are never enough. You always need more. The estimates are simply bad.

Comment: "Since we can not have this delay" Why not? Are you really in such a bad situation that you can't go back and say "there was a problem with the project and we need an extra week."? If your answer is "yes", then isn't that a bad decision on the part of management? I'd politely suggest that's the real problem here, and focussing on the staff is missing the point. There's a saying: "Your lack of planning is not my emergency" and some of your staff may feel it applies here.

Comment: These are called `Monday` projects. Managed by people who always set Monday morning as a deadline. Assuming that if there are any problems on the project that they'll have the weekend to hit the deadline.

Answer (score 5):

You can't force someone to work overtime if its contract never stipulates it.

Unfortunately, I would see two solutions:

1) Managing to convince him to work overtime for the survival of the project.
   Drawback: Demotivation would certainly lead to bad codes, in order to quickly achieve tasks.

2) A little monetary compensation in order to motivate and provide clean code that works.

Comment: +1 and also 3) deliver key features in a first release by the deadline and others in a later release 4) delay the release a week 5) talk to employee about problems with weekend working & see whether employer can help, e.g. help with care for children or other dependants, offer paid overtime Mon-Fri, extra paid holiday after the deadline in exchange for working weekends etc